# Photos are not changing in my gallery using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, gallery, setinterval

1. My problem was different than I thought. My real problem is that the photos are not changing at all in the gallery. I don't know how I missed that, but I did. Any ideas?

   ```
   function startAdPage(){

              var curCounter = 10;

              function startCountdown() {

                 document.getElementById("countdown").value = curCounter;

                 curCounter--;

                 if (curCounter == -1) {

                   clearInterval(countdownInterval);

                   window.open('CVR2.html', 'width=400, height=600');

                 }
              }

              setInterval(changeAd, 2000);

              var countdownInterval = setInterval(startCountdown, 1000);

           }

            function changeAd() {

              for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++){

                 document.images[0].src = "images/cvb" + i + ".gif";

              }

           }
   ```

Comment: Yes? I don't understand why you said that

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem. Make a http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: @JamesG.- The reason you aren't able to replicate it, I've realized, is that the problem is different. My real problem is that the images stop changing after one iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like each time the `changeAd` function is getting called it runs through cvb1.gif through cvb3.gif, so at the end of the function the image src is always cvb3.gif. If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you could pull the `i` variable out of `changeAd` and increment it in `changeAd` after you set the image src.  Something like this maybe?

```
var i = 1;
function changeAd() {
    document.images[0].src = "images/cvb" + i + ".gif";
    i++;
    if (i > 3) {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Typically you want to stay away from global variables, though, and you could definitely tighten up/generalize the above code a bit, but hopefully it gets the idea across.